# How can i compile a c# winform application programmatically in c#

Tags: c#, .net

I have created a tool that open a c# Winform  application, the question is after I made some modification to the files I want to recompile those files programmatically using c#.

Comment: The answer would depend on whether the target is net framework or net core. Please edit your question to provide this information

Comment: for a question of this nature you really need to put more words as to what you are trying to do .. , you create a tool, what tool, how does it open WinForm applications, you mean you created an OS which can understand .net? Modified what files, i mean at this point im not sure if the tool is just visual studio and it not, then you need to explain more.

Comment: Hello i appreciate your comment , i found the solution by using CSharpCodeProvider , my tool is king of ide that load a c# winform application that mean it load all files included in the solution , so if a file content is changed i should compile the folder who contains  all these files , so thank you so much man

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using `CSharpCodeProvider`. You can find more information about this `class` in [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.csharp.csharpcodeprovider?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0).

Answer (score 0):

after searching i have use this solution :
String[] csFiles = CopyAllSourceFilesToCLASSESFolder().ToArray();

```
        String[] referenceAssemblies = { "System.dll", "System.Drawing.dll", "System.Windows.Forms.dll", "ICSharpCode.TextEditor.dll", "System.Xml.dll", "System.IO.dll", "System.ComponentModel.dll" , "System.Data.dll" , "System.linq.dll" };


            CSharpCodeProvider codeProvider = new CSharpCodeProvider();
            ICodeCompiler icc = codeProvider.CreateCompiler();
            string Output = "Out.exe";

            System.CodeDom.Compiler.CompilerParameters parameters = new CompilerParameters(referenceAssemblies);
            //Make sure we generate an EXE, not a DLL
            parameters.GenerateExecutable = true;
            parameters.OutputAssembly = Output;

            CompilerResults results = icc.CompileAssemblyFromFileBatch(parameters, csFiles);

            if (results.Errors.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (CompilerError CompErr in results.Errors)
                {
                ErrorTextBox.Text = ErrorTextBox.Text +
                                "Line number " + CompErr.Line +
                                ", Error Number: " + CompErr.ErrorNumber +
                                ", '" + CompErr.ErrorText + ";" +
                                Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine;
                }
            }
            else
            {
            //Successful Compile
            ErrorTextBox.ForeColor = Color.Blue;
            ErrorTextBox.Text = "Success!";
                //If we clicked run then launch our EXE
            }

            Process.Start(Output);
```

Comment: just trying to understand, what would be editing those files.? seems more like your looking for the build commands, i would agree with Wikior depends on whether the target is net framework or net core. you would then just need to look for that. seems odd like why would System.dll change?

Comment: i mean by editing files : add some line code or delete some function everything , is a .net framework

Comment: would be more interesting if you specific exactly what your doing, open a c# Winform application, do you mean read a c# file and display as text for modifying? or do u mean actually lunching the app, and if launched how would it modify itself.